# SQL query , cannot recognise '('select

Tags: sql, subquery

```
select * 
from TABLE_A 
where ID = (select ID 
            from TABLE_B as b 
            inner join TABLE_C as c on b.id = c.id 
            where b.date = "2021-10-31");
```

Cannot recognise input near '(' 'select' 'ID'

Comment: (1) '2021-10-31' , most DBMSes want single quotes for a string literal. (2) specify an alias, `(select b.ID ..`  I guess.

Answer (score 0):

There is a correction in your query.

As inner select query will return the collection of Ids, you need to use 'in' keyword instead of '='.

After modification your query should look like this:

```
select * from TABLE_A where ID in (select ID from TABLE_B as b inner join TABLE_C as c on b.id = c.id where b.date = "2021-10-31");
```